# ios uitableviewcell item equal height to superview storyboard interface builder

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, uicollectionview, interface-builder

In order to get a consistent size ratio between my views and the device, I make an equal width/height constraint between the view and the superview. However, when designing a UITableViewCell or a UICollectionViewCell, I can't find this option in the interface builder. I need to set a ratio between a view inside a cell and the superview. What is the cleanest way to accomplish this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in the storyboard and have to do it in code:

For **UITableView**:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return tableView.frame.size.width;
}
```

For **UICollectionView**:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    int columns = 2; // Change this to whatever you want
    float width = collectionView.frame.size.width / columns;
    return CGSizeMake(width, width);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your `UITableViewCell` the same size as superview of its table, you should do this:

1) Setup constraints to `UITableView` to equal width/height to superview, also setup its origin (for example center x/y in superview).

2) Return size for cell:

case `UITableViewCell`:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  return tableView.frame.size.height;
}
```

case `UICollectionViewCell`:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  return collectionView.frame.size;
}
```

Comment: sorry, I was a bit unclear, I don't need the cell to be the size of the superview, I need a view inside the cell to be the size of the superview. I've updated my question to be more specific.

Comment: @Siamaster, superview of tableView?

Comment: yes, or the tableview, just not in proportion to the cell itself.